# Https do not start in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, https

I have been set ssl config on apache in my CentOS server.
When I restart apache server, error occurs following this.

> [warn] module ssl_module is already loaded, skipping
>   (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
>   (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
>   no listening sockets available, shutting down
>   Unable to open logs

So my httpd don't start.

I comment "Listen 443" line and "LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so" Line.

Then apache starts well.

But I want to uncomment these lines.
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Check all your apache .conf file, you may have them already wrote in another file.

Comment: Or you may have another process listening on the 443 port

Comment: Thanks Froggiz and Fredi.
I have already wrote "Listen 443" line in another conf file.